# How to convert windows form application to windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows form application which has some functions like file deletion and result data deletion according to the threshold date given by the user. Since this has some issues while reaching the threshold i am trying to convert it to a windows service how to give the timer event and give the references from the already existing project to this project.

Comment: no way to convert, you just write one service.

Comment: A windows service cannot have a user interface, so there is no way to just "convert" it

Comment: Okay My doubt is i need to make user specify the File path which needed to be deleted and the threshold date with values in the service how can i do it?

Comment: You need two separate applications, one of which is a service and the other of which has a user interface.  Depending on your needs, these two parts might need to communicate directly (via whatever IPC mechanism you think most appropriate) or the user interface part might just configure the settings for the service part.

Comment: I have to make the services in the form of API and make it used by the UI can that be okay

Comment: This will give you the path of each user `string CONFIG_FOLDER = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) +"\\DummyFolder" + "\\" + "Your UserName" + "dummy.dat";`

Comment: Thank you the issue got solved